# Output formatting with right margin adjusters

Tags: python

The input data must contain (the text file) two integers (inches) specifying the left and right margins, respectively, to be used in generating the output listing. With these margins in mind, your program should process the remaining text in the file. The program should include as many words as can “fit” between the margins. No words should extend beyond the right margin. (Note: your program need not “right justify” the text! It must simply observe the margins.)

I already know how to use formatter.push_margin()

Comment: Are you using a specific document type? A document writing package? What solutions have you considered?

Comment: Sounds like an assignment that you have not attempted on your own.

Comment: What exactly is your question to us?